# how to make minepy.MINE run faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a numerical matrix of 2500*2500. To calculate the MIC (maximal information coefficient) for each pair of vectors, I am using minepy.MINE,  but this is taking forever, can I make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

first, use the latest version of minepy. Second, you can use a smaller value of "alpha" parameter, say 0.5 or 0.45. In this way, you will reduce the computational time in despite of characteristic matrix accuracy.